# What HTTP response code should be used for an OPTION request?

Tags: http, http-response-codes, http-options-method

I noticed that the [Mozilla HTTP response codes documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/HTTP_response_codes) states that

> The methods PUT, DELETE, and OPTIONS can never result in a 200 OK
>   response.

However it doesn't make clear what response should actually be used. My best guess would be 204:

> 204 : No Content
>
> There is no content to send for this request, but the headers may be
>   useful. The user-agent may update its cached headers for this resource
>   with the new ones.

Can anyone comment as to whether or not this is the correct code to be using to response to an OPTIONS request?

Comment: Interestingly, [Alan Dean’s HTTP headers status flow chart](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Http-headers-status.png) suggests 200.

Comment: Nice catch.. Now go ahead and update MDN wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in that case the Mozilla documentation is plainly wrong.

Comment: [this](http://books.google.de/books?id=XUaErakHsoAC&lpg=PP1&dq=restful%20web%20services&pg=PA197#v=onepage) agrees with you. `DELETE` can be `200 OK`

Comment: Hiroto: I really don't care whether some other sources say the same. What's relevant is the specification.

Comment: How is this an answer? This looks to be a comment, not a answer. You stated no sources, you made no explanation. You simply told the OP that Mozilla was wrong without explaining why and without supplying sources (alternative documentation, specification, publications, SOMETHING).

Comment: It's a statement of fact. You can easily verify it by looking at the *actual* HTTP specification (IETF RFC 7230...5).

Comment: @JulianReschke Highly unconstructive and unhelpful is all I'm saying. Maybe an explanation similar to Michael Foukarakis? Seeing as these answers are typically most helpful for their explanations and references, I found this to be quite uninformative and, quite frankly, useless. I don't think I've seen an Answer on SO worse than this one; especially given that it was the accepted response.

Comment: Again, it's a statement of fact, and last time I checked, this text was removed from the Mozilla documentation. Can we please move on?

Answer (score 7):

I use `204 No Content` because an `OPTIONS` response doesn't have any content.

Answer (score 5):

The (updated, btw) RFCs for HTTP 1.1 clearly state `200 OK` is an acceptable response for all 3 methods, see section 6.3.1 of [RFC 7231](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231.txt).

Answer (score 1):

RFC2616 clearly mentions a 200 response and requirements for a 200 response:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html